# What's maximum of bookmark and history in defaut browser in Android

Tags: browser, bookmarks, browser-history

A few days ago I viewed a site that I now want to go back to. However I can't find it in my history. I can't remember the exact day, hence my question about how long this is kept.

Answer (score 3):

It only limited to your phones internal memory

Answer (score 0):

It happens the same with me. I have to delete latest logs in order to see the older ones. And I'm trying to export/copy my browsing history to chrome which is the best.